# Converting Extended ASCII Characters to Hexadecimal or Plain Text

Tags: vb.net

I have a program written in VB.NET and I have a textbox for the RFID tag (which is in ASCII format) and then convert it to a simple text format to be saved to my database.

How can I convert ASCII to plain text to save to my database?

Comment: ASCII **is** plain text format...

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the `Chr` function for conversion.  For example,

```
Dim c As Char = Chr(asciiInt)
```

[Chr documentation is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Can I have a full code sir for the conversion? Forgive me but I am a newbie on this. Thanks sir.

Comment: It would depend on the formatting of the ascii values stored in your text box.